# how to coneect to amaonz RDS localhost from my pc

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

i try to connect to my amazon RDS server in my home pc
but i cant to do that i get a error:
this is my code:

> $mysqli = new mysqli('server.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306',
>   'serverName', 'serverPassword', 'serverTable');
>   $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');  var_dump($mysqli);

but i get an error:

[image]

in my SecurityGroup at amazon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons which could lead to this issue. Few of them are

- Placing RDS instance in private subnet
- Security group restrictions
- NACL restrictions

In your case, its most likely you have attached a security group to amazon RDS instance which is not accessible from outside. Also make sure you have enabled public access to your database instance in RDS.

Answer (score 0):

i fix that

looks at DB Instances in RDS:
dont forget to do yes for Publicly Accessible :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAuY4.png)